# Spring @RequestMapping deserializer

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

This is what I have:

**SomeController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class SomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/bar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Resource<Baz>> createCampaign(@RequestBody Foobar foobar) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, I need to use a custom `JsonDeserialiser` for `foobar`, but only for this particular endpoint, every other endpoint with has `Foobar` as its `@RequestBody` should use the default. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Can't you just tweak with the data in Foobar after serialization?

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine an other way than doing things *by hand*. Get your request body as a plain string and call you custom JsonDeserializer with it :

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Resource<Baz>> createCampaign(@RequestBody String body) {
    //do your custom deserialization
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How is different the deserialization of this instance in compare to the other ones?

Which version of of Jackson are you using? Jackson 2 enables pretty cool stuff for deserialization.

First option, you can use the [Jackson Builder](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/Presentation-Jackson-2.0#support-builder-style-objects), to customize

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = FooBarBuilder.class)
public class FooBar {
    ...
    public static class FooBarBuilder() {
        public FooBar build(){...}
    }
}
```

Second option, if your actual FooBar is an subtype of a see [Handling polymorphic types](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations#handling-polymorphic-types) to resolve the actual instance of your class.

Hope it helps!